# How does C# verify the C# Private Definition?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I use private and public methods all the time. However, I do not understand why they work.
Creating a small Hello World Program:

```
public class CallPublicHelloWorld
{
    public void CallHelloWorld()
    {
        publicHelloWorld();
        privateHelloWorld();
    }

    private void privateHelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    public void publicHelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The IL created for the public method:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldstr      "Hello World"
IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  ret
```

The IL created for the private method:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldstr      "Hello World"
IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  ret
```

It's the exact same.

How does the JIT differentiate and verify that the private/public rules were followed?

Comment: Refer this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: Well, I was wondering about the guts more so than anything. I understand that private methods can only be accessed through the same classes and such. I am curious HOW it does what it does at a low level.

Comment: What does what? You're IDE forbidds you accessing private fields explicittly from outer classes, what are you asking exactly? You want the implementation details of dotnet compiler or Visual Studio?

Comment: The prohibition is only weak. It doesn't exist on the assembly level, only in C#/IL. And even in C#, you can go around it if you have access to reflection. It's there to help you code, not for security.

Comment: There's a lot more to the type system at run-time than what you can see by looking at the IL.

Comment: The question, after your edits, is still *way* too broad.  Explaining the entire type system of a language is something entire books are written on.  You can fit that into an SO answer.

Comment: I have edited the question to reduce the scope. Hopefully it'll work. What are some books that touch on the subject?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You omitted the relevant lines from the generated IL:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void privateHelloWorld () cil managed 

.method public hidebysig instance void publicHelloWorld () cil managed
```

And that's all there is to it. See the accessibility section in this [Common Type System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page.

When mangling the IL to call the private method and compiling it with ilasm, at runtime you'll get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Program.Main(System.String[])' to access method 'CallPublicHelloWorld.privateHelloWorld()' failed.
>
> at Program.Main(String[] args)

So there *is* an accessibility check performed by the runtime.

Comment: Haha, You are absolutely right. I had originally asked a private/public implementation difference. I was told it was too broad so I tried to rescope the question without editing my IL code. Thank you

Comment: So, what _is_ your question? :) When calling a private method on another class, the C# compiler will complain.

Comment: The question originally was: How does the C# compiler implement private/public definitions? Looking back on that, it was obviously too broad.

Comment: @Dude then the answer seems to be "by compiling it into the equivalent MSIL". :)

Comment: Haha! I was curious if the private/public tags changed the code at compilation time. I wanted to know if these fields were just for the programmer/IDE or did it change the assembler.